# [Python][OpenPyXL] Not working SUMIF formula in Excel

Tags: python, openpyxl, formulas

I have very simple code in Python. I need use EXCEL formula sumif and put result to the cell.

Why it works:?

```
bus_tab.cell(column=3, row=1, value="=SUM(C8:C200)")
```

But this not? I need use "sumif" formula

```
bus_tab.cell(column=3, row=1, value="=SUMIF(E8:E200; 1; C8:C200)")
```

Link to error while opening document:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Parameters must be separated by commas. See http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.4/usage.html#using-formulae